# ‘double& Point::operator[](unsigned int)’ is inaccessible within this context

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I have two classes set up as follows:

```
class Point {
protected:
    double coords[3];

public:
    Point(double x, double y, double z) {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setZ(z);
    };
    ~Point() {};
    double x() {return coords[0];};
    double y() {return coords[1];};
    double z() {return coords[2];};
    void setX(double x) {
        coords[0] = x;
    };
    void setY(double y) {
        coords[1] = y;
    };
    void setZ(double z) {
        coords[2] = z;
    };
    double &operator[](unsigned int x) {
        return coords[x];
    }
};


class Vector:Point {

public:
    Vector(double x, double y, double z);
    ~Vector() {};
    double norm();
    void normalize();
};
```

Now whenever I try to do something like:

```
Vector v;
printf("%d\n", v[0]);
```

I get:

```
error: ‘Point’ is not an accessible base of ‘Vector’
error: ‘double& Point::operator[](unsigned int)’ is inaccessible
error: within this context
```

Why?

Comment: `class Vector : **public** Point`

Comment: It must be `class Vector: public Point` I guess

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Class inheritance is by default private. You must explicitly tell the compiler that you want public inheritance:

```
class Vector : public Point { // public

public:
    Vector(double x, double y, double z);
    ~Vector() {};
    double norm();
    void normalize();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The default inheritance specifier for classes is private.